# MS Office PIA Com Interop Error

Tags: .net, excel, com-interop

My app reads an excel file to parse and upload records. I use .NET 4 and PIA.
The app runs fine on my Win7 machine. 
But on Win2003 server it is giving this error on below code line

```
var xlApp = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();
```

**Retrieving the COM class factory for component with CLSID {00024500-0000-0000-C000-000000000046} failed due to the following error: 80040154.**

Please give some pointers to solve this.

Comment: Getting Office Addins/Addons to run on server systems can be a real hassle. Did you check if the correct PIA is installed on your Win2003 machine? Are you developing on Win7 x64 and deploying to Win2003 32-Bit? Did you create an installer for your app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The very first thing you have to do is to make sure that Office is actually installed on that server.  You can't use a PIA without the component being present.

Second thing you have to do is worry about the bitness of your process.  A server is likely to boot the 64-bit version of Windows but have the 32-bit version of Office installed.  Which means that your process needs to be 32-bit as well.  Project + Properties, Build tab, change the Platform target setting from AnyCPU to x86.  If this code runs in IIS then enable 32-bit application pool support.

Comment: I could gather strongly the reason being that MS Office is not installed. Though I am yet to try it after installing office. thanks.